# Integrate data in the child or parent BU in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sfmc-business-unit

Our client has a corporate edition with 2 BU (one parent and one Child BU). He wants to connect service cloud to his SFMC org.
In the future, they may need to deploy other countries (BU) on the SFMC org.

Should the data for this first BU (included data from MC connector) be injected in the child BU or the parent BU ? knowing that at that stage, they don't know yet if the other SFMC BUs will need to integrate with other Salesforce orgs or the same Salesforce org.

Thank you

Regards

Ludivine

Comment: Please review my answer, and remember to mark it as accepted/upvote if you've found it helpful

Answer (score 4):

Always integrate to ENT (root BU) and use automation studio in ENT to sync into child BUs using Shared Data Extensions. Even the day you choose to upgrade to Multi-Org connector, the integration still is done with the ENT BU, which technically holds all the synchronised data extensions, across all the BUs.

This will still allow you to inject contacts into journeys in any child BU that is mapped to that respective Org in Core. There is a setting in connector configuration in Core, where you select BUs applicable for the connector to interact with:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is not a standard solution for all clients.

First of all, how is the information about the rest of the countries structured in Service Cloud.

Secondly, having one Child BU per each country is a good approach but depending on the data policy of the customer (e.g. the all subscribers list is shared across the BUs) or other restrictions you may consider a Multi-Org architecture VS Single-Org.

In any case, in this type of use cases, the Connector is normally configured at Parent BU level and from there you shared the data needed with the child BU accordingly.